# UITableview doesn't scroll up when keyboard is shown

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm having a startview like this:

[image]

Where The first half of the screen is a Google map and the second half is a UITableview with in the header cell a UISearchbar.

When I click on the searchbar this happens on big screens but on small screens my uisearchbar is covered with the keyboard.

[image]

As you can see , when the keyboard shows up the searchbar moves a little bit to the bottom. I don't want that. It should push everything up so the Tableview is visible.

I followed a tutorial about contentInset. But it doesn't do anything.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillShow:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification
                                               object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(keyboardWillHide:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification
                                               object:nil];
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)keyboardWillShow:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSLog(@"KeyboardWillshow");
    // Step 1: Get the size of the keyboard.
    CGSize keyboardSize = [[[notification userInfo] objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


    // Step 2: Adjust the bottom content inset of your scroll view by the keyboard height.
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(0.0, 0.0, keyboardSize.height, 0.0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;


    // Step 3: Scroll the target text field into view.
    CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;
    aRect.size.height -= keyboardSize.height;
    if (!CGRectContainsPoint(aRect, _searchBar.frame.origin) ) {
        CGPoint scrollPoint = CGPointMake(0.0, _searchBar.frame.origin.y - (keyboardSize.height-15));
        [self.tableView setContentOffset:scrollPoint animated:YES];
        NSLog(@"Scrolled");
    }
}

- (void)keyboardWillHide:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    UIEdgeInsets contentInsets = UIEdgeInsetsZero;
    self.tableView.contentInset = contentInsets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = contentInsets;
}
```

It comes in the if test where Scrolled is printed. And still nothing happens.

Where _searchBar is my UISearchbar variable.

Anyone an idea?

EDIT:

Solved the problem except the UISearchbar jump crapy down when clicking on it. This creates a gap like you can see on the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: you have to reposition whole view i.e containing searchbar and tableview above the keyboard.

Comment: Yes but how? I can via a delegate let the containercontroller know that the keyboard is up. But then I need to say (using autolayout) that my uitableview's bottom must be equal to the top of the keyboard. And I don't see how..

Comment: you can minus the height of keyboard from the while view height and change the table y position too.

Comment: Thanks. That works. But the UISearchbar creates a gap between the other views. Because it jumps.. Like you see on the image.

Comment: you can set this using the UIVIew animation.

Comment: I know, but I need to know how much the gap is.

Comment: between map and serachbar?

Comment: Yes, I've edited the post. Added a screenshot with in red indicated what I mean. The searchbar just does this. Don't know why.

Comment: accept the answer as it helped you. and now its another problem not related to the question you had asked. So better you ask it as another question. So you can get better response

Comment: did you checked the position of the searchbar?

Comment: Found the solution. Need to set      [self setEdgesForExtendedLayout:UIRectEdgeNone]; Thanks for all your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the example below.

```
- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)aNotification

{

NSDictionary* info = [aNotification userInfo];

CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;


CGRect aRect = self.view.frame;

aRect.size.height -= kbSize.height;

float height =150;
float yPoint = aRect.size.height-height;


[self.tblSearch setFrame:CGRectMake(self.tblSearch.frame.origin.x
                                    , yPoint, self.tblSearch.frame.size.width, height)];



}
```

Answer (score 1):

If your searchbar, tableview and mapview is all place in a view,

and you want to push the tableview and searchbar visible when keyboardWillshow,

you should update `frame` instead of `contentInset`.

Comment: I'm having a controller that has my map and tableview. So I need to update frame?

Comment: Yes, like @BSKANIA say, just reposition the whole view.

Comment: Done it. And now my content is shown. But still the uisearchbar moves a bit ( it looks crapy it does a sort of jump to the bottom )